# How to check if which radio button is selected using django

Tags: python, html, django

I have 5 radio buttons and each have different values but as user can only select 1 option out of 5 and after selecting the value of radio button should be stored in my django models.

This is my html code

```
<div class="col">
 <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason1" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason1">
      Casual Leave
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason2">
        Medical Leave
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason3">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason3">
        Earned Leave
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason4">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason4">
        Office Duty
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason5">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason5">
        Compensatory Off
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

*this code contains form tag

My Django function

```
def leaveapplicationsubmit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reason1 = request.POST['reason1']
        reason2 = request.POST['reason2']
        reason3 = request.POST['reason3']
        reason4 = request.POST['reason4']
        reason5 = request.POST['reason5']
        if 'reason1' in request.POST:
          reason = "Casual Leave"
        elif 'reason2' in request.POST:
          reason="Medical Leave"
        elif 'reason3' in request.POST:
          reason="Earned Leave"
        elif 'reason4' in request.POST:
          reason="Office Duty"
        elif 'reason5' in request.POST:
          reason="Compensatory Off"
        else:
          return HttpResponse('Please select the reason')                 
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

Please help me with it, I really need that

Answer (score 1):

All of the buttons have `name="reason"`.  That is the name you should look for in the code, not reason1, reason2 etc.  Those are ids, not names.

Also, each button needs a `value` attribute, so you can tell which one was pressed.

Look at the examples here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Comment: I tried that but when I use this I am unable to select other radio options

Answer (score 0):

In views write this code, here `reason_` will hold the value which will be selected by the user and in HTML code write it as given here `https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp` then `reason_` will hold the value of the selected option

```
def radio(request):                  
    if request.method == "POST":
        d = request.POST
        for key,value in d.items():                       
            if  key == "reason":
                reason_ = value
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your radios button input tags should have values, Your HTML code will
> look like below, notice that I have put value="" in every input tag.

```
<div class="col">
 <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason1" value="Casual Leave" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason1">
      Casual Leave
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason2" value="Medical Leave">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason2">
        Medical Leave
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason3" value="Earned Leave">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason3">
        Earned Leave
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason4" value="Office Duty">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason4">
        Office Duty
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="reason5" value="Compensatory Off">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="reason5">
        Compensatory Off
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Then your django view will look like this

```
def leaveapplicationsubmit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reason = request.POST['reason']

        #Use your reason value to do what you wish

    else:
        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: I have added some explanation